# What does expectation ( E(x) ) practically mean in Statistics?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I know the mathematical definition of Expectation- Sum of the product of the probability of an event occurring - P(x), and the value corresponding with the actual observed occurrence of the event. ( in the case of a discrete random variable )

But I don't get the practical aspect of it. I don't understand what the expectation of an event actually is trying to tell and how it can be useful, I just understand the mathematical aspect of it

Comment: It's a weighted average.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is simply a probability-weighted average of all events that may occur. For example, if you roll a fair six-sided die, the probability of getting each outcome $1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$ is $1/6$. Then the expected value is $$\sum_{i=1}^6\frac16\cdot i=3.5$$
which is the weighted average of each outcome. This means that if you roll a dice for many many times, the average of all the rolls would approach $3.5$.